# What is recommended library for unit testing Playframework 2.3.7 RESTful api

Tags: postgresql, scala, rest, unit-testing, slick

I want to unit test Play Framework  2.3.7 RESTful api. I'm using Scala 2.11, Play 2.3.7, slick 3.0, PostgreSql 9.4. I have implemented REST api for CRUD operation.  now I would like to unit test it.

I found several of them by googling. I realize many of them are depreciated or found known issues.

So what is newer, easier, recommended framework available? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I've been testing my Play Rest services using JUnit and Specification.

```
import org.junit.runner._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestAddressController extends Specification {

  "Address Controller" should {
    "make findAll request" in new WithApplication {
      val request = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/address")).get
      status(request) must equalTo(OK)
      contentType(request) must beSome.which(_ == "application/json")
    }
}
```